# Independent margin for list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h0qu4ffv/ I set the `margin-top` of 1 list item to be `50px`, but all of them follow this style.

How can I have an independent margin for each list item, or, better yet, what is the correct way in order to have an unordered horizontal list with each item to different distance (from top, e.g.)?

Comment: You just posted the same link as I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making the `position:relative`, then adjusting the items using `top`

```
<ul>
 <li>
    Item 1
 </li>
 <li id="seconditem">
    Item 2
 </li>
 <li id="lastitem">
    Item 3
 </li>
</ul>
```

then your css

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid green;
position: relative;
}

#lastitem {
top: 30px;
}
#seconditem {
top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland I try ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:nth-child`

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/h0qu4ffv/8/)

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top:50px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have different styles on each element of the list, is to define a different style for each one.someting like this:

```
<ul>
    <li style="margin-top: margin1">
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li style="margin-top: margin2">
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li style="margin-top: margin3">
        Item 3
    </li>
</ul>
```